# Gtk+ with Code::Blocks fail at build

Tags: build, compiler-errors, gtk, config, codeblocks

First, I am sorry for my bad English, I am French.

I tried to install the Gtk+ library with Code::Blocks, and I created a project just for try to use the stuff.

So, I used the method given at this page :
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16468.0

And I put this test code in main.c :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void OnDestroy(GtkWidget *pWidget, gpointer pData);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *pWindow;
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    pWindow = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    tk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), 320, 200);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(pWindow), "Chapitre Fenetre");
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pWindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(OnDestroy), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(pWindow);
    gtk_main();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void OnDestroy(GtkWidget *pWidget, gpointer pData)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

And I tried to build, but I get this error on the Code::Blocks build log:

**Execution of 'mingw32-g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\Simulation POP.exe" obj\Debug\main.o   -LC:/MinGW/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl' in 'C:\Users\Habib\Documents\Simulation POP' failed.**

Please, have-you got an explanation ?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I desinstalled Code::Blocks, Gtk+ and all of the other stuff, and I just restart like this :

**(1)** C:\Program Files\Code::Blocks\
**(2)** C:\Program Files\Code::Blocks\Gtk+\

Then, I put the path (2)\bin\ in the Variable Path Environnement.
I configured Code::Blocks without the tutorial, just with the bin, gtk+ and lib directory.
I executed the main.c Hello Word, and everything was good.
If anyone has the same problem, just send me a mail or ask the question in the same topic.